# Maximum match lines in transforms. Conf

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

How many match condition statements can be in transforms.conf of splunk. I see that with more than 700 lines of match conditions the data is not getting ingested and it is not getting recognised or processed, but with less than 650 lines of match cases data gets ingested.

Comment: What do you mean by "match cases"?  Please provide an example.

Comment: Meant match(<str>, <regex>) statement.

Comment: `match(<str>, <regex>)` is not a valid transforms.conf setting.  Please share a snippet of the file.